# LISP: Order items of a list in ascending order

Tags: list, lisp

I have a list L composed from random numbers

```
(defvar L '(1 4 2 6 4 3 4 1 9 5))
```

How to order it in ascending order?

```
list in ascending order is: L(1 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 9)
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(sort L #'<)
```

or

```
(sort (copy-list L) #'<)
```

if you don't want to modify `L` in-place. If you want to use `L` afterward to get to the sorted list, rebind it:

```
(setf L (sort L #'<))
```

Comment: You mean:  `(setf L (sort L #'<))`. If you don't capture the return value back into the variable `L`, then `L` is not the sorted list. Also, if the value of `L` is derived from a list literal, like the student's `defvar` given in the question, this is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Kaz: of course, the output needs to go somewhere, but the OP need not reset `L`; e.g., they can pass the result from `sort` to a function. Where is the undefined behavior documented?

Comment: larsmans: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_sort_.htm  -- "sort and stable-sort destructively sort sequences according to the order determined by the predicate function" Unless you rebind L, the original L is now in an indeterminate order (although that is probably only a concern for lists, arrays should be good as-is).

Comment: @Vatine: right, so if you want to access `L` afterward, it has to be re-bound, but if you don't need it anymore (admittedly strange since it's defined using `defvar`) then the answer is complete.

Comment: larsmans: Exactly. Plus, sorting constant data is a little bit iffy, since compilers are allowed to coalesce constants.